# MySQL query with multiple AND OR statements

Tags: mysql

I'd like to get all values from my table that correspond with (either Nombre or Descripcion, or both) **AND** (either Post, Post2 or Post3, or all three of them)

Does this query make sense? I'm not sure about the brackets...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Nombre LIKE '...' OR Descripcion LIKE '...') AND (Post LIKE '...' OR Post2 LIKE '...' OR Post3 LIKE '...')";
```

thanks!

Comment: @w3shivers there is no need of last extra bracket

Comment: @amit Sorry also see that now. Will remove the comment. Got confused with my own code I'm working on.